# Why training VGG16 CNN with images from scratch doesn't show up convergence?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I'm training the VGG16 CNN model with the "Imagenet" weights. There is no convergence when training the model from scratch. I have used a saved model after one epoch from another machine and started training on top of that. What could be the issue?

`Using Learning Rate - 0.0001 / 0.001 ( Tried using both )`
`Training Images - RGB (1,00,000 images)`
`When training the model with Imagenet Pretrained weights from scratch there is no convergence. The training accuracy stands still (70%) after several epochs. The loss (88%) is not reducing.`
`When training the model with Imagenet Pretrained weights with a .h5 model ( Got from another machine after first epoch with the same configuration ) there was convergence. The accuracy raised epoch by epoch up to 90% & above and the loss reduced gradually.`

## **What could be the actual reason?**

Comment: This question is impossible to answer without all the details, including code.

Comment: Maybe the first epochs on re-training imply too much changes in the VGG network. Try to first freeze VGG layers excepted the last layer for a few epochs

Comment: Can you share your code here.